# jQuery: selecting an element having a certain id and a certain class, both as variables

Tags: jquery

I have two variables `x` and `y`. Can I select the element having an `id` of `x` as well as a `class` of `y` with jQuery?

Comment: Yes, of course you can: `$('#' + x + '.' + y)`. Where did you get stuck?

Comment: although it still seems weird why you have to select with a class AND an id. An id may only be once on the page, so why double check with a class?

Comment: @daniel: we often use class-names to reflect/imply a given state of an element ("selected," "active," etc); so it's not unexpected that selecting an element by both `id` and `class` is occasionally required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector:

```
$('#'+x+'.'+y)
```

Will select an id x and a class y, but as danielwinter said there is not really a point unless you are trying to see if an element with a certain id has been assigned a class in which case you are better off using:

```
if($('#'+x).hasClass(y)){
    //whatever here
}
```

Whoever comes behind you will understand your intent more than:

```
if($('#'+x+'.'+y).length > 0){
    //whatever here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example
**HTML**

```
<input type='button' id='myId' class='myClass' value='Hello World'>
```

**JS** the following 4 functions are the same

```
$('input.myClass#myId').on('click', function(){
    // do the same action
});
$('input#myId.myClass').on('click', function(){
        // do the same action
});
$('.myClass#myId').on('click', function(){
        // do the same action
});
$('#myId.myClass').on('click', function(){
        // do the same action
});
```